# scaning error for Laser Scan Matcher

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping, robot-localization, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using ZED camera and the wheel odometry, fused together with robot_localization. My code uses laser_scan_matcher with gmapping to build the map of the environment. I am using deptimage_to_laserscan to convert 3D point cloud to 2D laser scan.

```
    <launch>

<!--EKF Launch -->
<include file="$(find robot_localization)/launch/EKF_Odom.launch" />

<!--Zed Camera Launch -->
<include file="$(find zed_wrapper)/launch/zed.launch" />

<arg name="base_frame"              default="zed_camera_center"/>


<!-- Depth_image to Laser_Scan -->
<node pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan" name="depthimage_to_laserscan">
        <param name="scan_height" value="100"/>
        <param name="output_frame_id" value="$(arg base_frame)"/>
        <param name="range_min" value="0.3"/>
        <param name="range_max" value="60"/>
        <remap from="image" to="/zed/depth/depth_registered"/>
    <remap from="scan" to ="/scan"/>

 </node>
 

<!-- Laser Scan Match -->
<node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">

    <param name="fixed_frame" value = "world"/>
    <param name="base_frame" value="wheelchair_base"/>
    <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="false"/>
    <param name="use_odom" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_imu" value="false"/>
    <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
    <param name="publish_pose" value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="false"/>
    <param name="use_vel" value="false"/>
    
 </node>

<!-- Gmapping -->

 <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <param name="map_udpate_interval" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="delta" value="0.02"/>
    <param name="base_frame" value="base_frame"/>
 </node> 

<!--RVIZ launch -->
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz"/>

</launch>
```

This is my launch file. When I launch it I get error:

```
[ WARN] [1552782652.945326528]: Laser has to be mounted planar! Z-coordinate has to be 1 or -1, but gave: 1.14000
  icp_loop: failed: after trimming, only 51 correspondences.
icp: ICP failed for some reason. 
[ WARN] [1552782652.949929738]: Error in scan matching
[ WARN] [1552782652.978282773]: Laser has to be mounted planar! Z-coordinate has to be 1 or -1, but gave: 1.14000
```

Any idea how I can fix this? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Hdbot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318654/scaning-error-for-laser-scan-matcher/) by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2019-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out the issues, the base_frame was wrongly written.

---

Originally posted by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) with karma: 36 on 2019-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-03-18**:
Can you please explain what you mean by this?

**Comment by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) on 2019-03-19**:\

this is correct way. If you notice in my original code I had it as base_frame. So the system was confused as to while is the correct frame and it used camera as the frame. Since the camera is on angle it gave that error.